# Unity 2D The Bounce of The Ball After Hitting The Wall

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I want to make the ball be bounced after hitting the wall.What i have to write to the script?[The image of the thing i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92m7K.png)

I searched about this on the internet but i couldnt find what i want.I asked to ChatGPT it didnt work.

Comment: well if you hit anything at 90 degrees it  always comes back to you, so if you dont want that if this is the best you can do to explain that - this will be why you cant write it, if you cant explain it in good detail you arent ready to write it yet

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This is a vague answer, probably not something you should ask here, and its very simple so I don't know how you cant find it online. But I'll provide an answer anyway:

To make objects bounce, you need to use Physics Materials. To create one, right click on the project window, click create > 2D > Physics material 2D

[image]

Adjust the values to your liking

[image]

Then drag it onto your ball.

Comment: no worries, don't forget to mark it as answer so that it shows up.